# Android: onInterceptTouchEvent в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, ontouchlistener

Хочу реализовать закрытие фрагмента свайпом как в телеграме 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В принципе все получается, но с RecyclerView у меня OnTouchListener в SwipeBackView не вызывается. Собстна сам код:

```
public class SwipeBackView extends FrameLayout {

int clickX = 0;

private void swipe(MotionEvent event) {
    View mainLayout = getChildAt(0);
    int viewWidth = Math.round(mainLayout.getWidth());
    int getX = Math.round(event.getX());

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
            clickX = Math.round(event.getX());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение

            int swipe = Math.round(getX - clickX);
            if (swipe > 0) {
                Help.setTranslationX(mainLayout, swipe);
            } else {
                Help.setTranslationX(mainLayout, 0);
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // отпускание
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            clickX = 0;
            if (getX > (viewWidth / 2)) {
                mainLayout.setTranslationX(viewWidth);
            } else {
                mainLayout.setTranslationX(0);
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void init() {
    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            swipe(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

public SwipeBackView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public SwipeBackView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public SwipeBackView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}}
```

И layout

```
<anton.vk.vkontakte2.views.SwipeBackView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/list_view_attachments"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:layout_height="86dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llMsgCompose"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</anton.vk.vkontakte2.views.SwipeBackView>
```

Когда я тяну за *llMsgCompose* LinearLayout, то все работает, layout движется, а когда за *list_view_attachments* RecyclerView тогда не движется.

В гугле искал очень долго, но ничего рабочего не нашел. 
Что то типо:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Не помогает. Если я ловлю события через в onInterceptTouchEvent в своем SwipeBackView , тогда мой RecyclerView не скролится.

Как быть? Как правильно реализовать эту фичу?